# How to subtract Timestamps in excel which includes timezone, if anyone knows formula or any other way please do comment here

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to subtract these timestamps:

[image]

Comment: What have you considered so far?

Comment: Use a double unary on the data with a nested Substitute function to get rid of the T. Untested, but will probably work to return the date-timestamp as numeric values.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, absolutely, as simple as `SUBSTITUTE()` Function, with a double unary or `+0` or `/1` or `*1`, `=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," ")` and format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10))
```

As the format is always 10 long, you could also use a series of LEFT and MID with the formula DATE(), just like this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),MID(A2,9,2))
```